# How do I exclude absolute paths for tar?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am running a PHP script that gets me the absolute paths of files I want to tar up. This is the syntax I have:

```
tar -cf tarname.tar -C /www/path/path/file1.txt /www/path/path2/path3/file2.xls
```

When I untar it, it creates the absolute path to the files. How do I get just `/path` with everything under it to show?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want to remove the first n leading components of the file name, you need `strip-components`. So in your case, on extraction, do

```
tar xvf tarname.tar --strip-components=2
```

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) has a list of `tar`'s many options, including this one. Some earlier versions of `tar` use `--strip-path` for this operation instead.

Answer (score 53):

You are incorrectly using the `-C` switch, which is used for changing directories. So what you need to do is:

```
tar -cf tarname.tar -C /www/path path/file1.txt path2/path3/file2.xls
```

or if you want to package everything under `/www/path` do:

```
tar -cf tarname.tar -C /www/path .
```

You can use `-C` switch multiple times.

Comment: When I try to do that I get a file named dot added to my archive. tar -cf tarname.tar some_file_in_current_folder -C /some/path .

Comment: Try `tar -tvf tarname.tar` and you will see that this is not a file.

Answer (score 12):

For me the following works the best:

```
tar xvf some.tar --transform 's?.*/??g'
```

`--transform` argument is a replacement regex for sed, to which every extracted filepath is fed. Unlike `--strip-components`, it will remove all path information, not just fixed number of components.

Comment: Note that the long name option `--transform` is for GNU tar only. BSD tar's equivalent option is `-s` following `/old/new/[gps]` pattern, and using this way, as you said it will flatten the directory hierarchy, might not be useful in practice.

Comment: Best option when you don't know how deep the rabbit hole goes (I mean, your directory structure). 
Make sure all file names are unique across directories or you may experience unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many components are in the path, you could try this:

```
DIR_TO_PACK=/www/path/
cd $DIR_TO_PACK/..
tar -cf tarname.tar $(basename $DIR_TO_PACK)
```