# directory when creating a .tar.gz file includes home and public html folders

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I am using this command

```
tar -zcf acc.tar.gz /home/uname/public_html/project/js
```

it is creating the zip file fine, but zip file contains all the folders in `home->uname->public_html->projects/js..`

i want only js folder in the `zip`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to get only the `contents` of the `js folder`, and no sub-directory content:

```
tar -czf acc.tar.gz --no-recursion /home/uname/public_html/project/js/*
```

Try the following to change to the directory to avoid archiving the absolute path:

```
tar -czf acc.tar.gz -C /home/uname/public_html/project ./js
```

From the `man tar` page:

```
--no-recursion
    don't recurse into directories
-C, --directory DIR
    change to directory DIR
```

Comment: Thnx 4 ur response, but i want every thing in the js folder i just want my zip to contain only the js folder with all its content..

Comment: Right now my zip file contains hhome->uname->public_html->projects/js->js files folders,  i want the zip to contain js->js files folders

Comment: I get what you're seeking now.  I'll change the answer from: `tar -czf acc.tar.gz --no-recursion /home/uname/public_html/project/js/*` to: `tar -czf -C /home/uname/public_html/project ./js`.    Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153683/how-do-i-exclude-absolute-paths-for-tar

Comment: Awesome.. Ase Lars... Thnx a million.. :)